# Creating a similar product

Tags: us20160375946

In reference to the patent: [US20160375946](https://www.google.com/patents/US20160375946)

This patent has not been issued, and I have come up with a similar concept with different features. Am I able to bring my concept to market?

Comment: The big question is whether your "different features" are different enough to avoid infringement. We can't know that since we don't know your concept.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but with possible dire consequences later on.

At the moment, this is a patent application. An application gives the owner no actionable rights. That is, you can freely copy it, and cannot be successfully sued which it is only an application.

However, once the patent issues, the owner can have rights which retrospectively apply back to publication. That is, if you use the invention now, you may be liable for that use once the patent issues (even though it is only an application when you used it). These retrospective rights are called provisional rights.

The requirements for provisional rights is provided by [35 USC 154](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/35/154). That is, the invention must be claimed in the publication, and must be claimed in a substantially identical manner in the issued patent, and the infringer has actual notice of the publication.

Thus if your concept infringes the claims of that publication (that it, the "different features" are not quite different enough"), depending on how prosecution progresses, you may well be liable.

Comment: This is a good answer but it is possible the original posters "different features" are sufficiently different to avoid infringement.

Comment: @EricShain That's true. I seem to have glossed over that quite important part.

Comment: Maybe a little edit is in order?